# servlet / rest controller download log4j log file contents doesn't cleanly end

Tags: java, file, servlets, filereader, spring-restcontroller

In a Spring web app (though I don't think this is Spring-related), I made a REST GET resource that allows to download the current log4j2 file content, but requests (from both browsers and cUrl) don't terminate with the webapp deployed on the remote production server — while they normally end on my Windows development machine.

Moreover, cUrl says there are still bytes to receive:

```
* transfer closed with 3 bytes remaining to read
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (18) transfer closed with 3 bytes remaining to read
```

This is the relevant code:

```
// ...
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
// ...
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/logs", produces="application/json")
public class LogController {

    // ... 

    @GetMapping(path="/{appenderName}/contents", produces="text/plain")
    public void download(@PathVariable String appenderName, HttpServletResponse response) {

        // ...

        org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger rootLogger = LogManager.getRootLogger();
        if(rootLogger instanceof Logger) {
            Logger l = (Logger) rootLogger;

            if(l.getAppenders().containsKey(appenderName)) {
                Appender appender = l.getAppenders().get(appenderName);

                if(appender instanceof FileAppender) {
                    ((FileAppender) appender).getManager().flush();
                    final File f = new File(((FileAppender) appender).getFileName());

                    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
                    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + f.getName() + "\"");

                    Path tempCopy = Files.createTempFile("log-", null);
                    Files.copy(f.toPath(), tempCopy, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

                    response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(tempCopy.toFile().length()));

                    Reader reader = new FileReader(tempCopy.toFile());
                    IOUtils.copy(reader, response.getWriter());

                    reader.close();
                    tempCopy.toFile().delete();

                    // ...
```

I think the issue is with the `Content-length` header: on the Linux (Ubuntu) server, it only works if I subtract `3` to the file length:

```
response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(tempCopy.toFile().length() - 3));
```

I tried copying the original file to a temporary one before downloading, but it doesn't seem to help.

Of course everything is fine if I don't send any `Content-Length` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved specifying the character set in the `Content-Type` header:

```
response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
```

Without it the Linux server was returning:

```
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Comment: Missed it, also part of the truth, in most of the cases it is encoding related thing (headers, body), let me vote up you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like **cURL** related issue, which happens because of the `Content-Disposition` header's `filename` part (question here is about log's filename format, mostly it's date part).

The way `Content-Disposition` should be formed was originally described by the [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) and [RFC 2231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2231); so correct way to set `filename` part is by encoding it:

```
String fileName = URLEncoder.encode(f.getName(), "UTF-8");
response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```

---

### Additional information

Btw later [RFC 5987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987) introduced possibility of using encoding in optional "extensional" parameters (`filename*` in our case); it is supported by modern browsers.

It gives you a possibility to add optional "extensional" parameters:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;
                     filename="EURO rates";
                     filename*=utf-8''%e2%82%ac%20rates
```

Here user agents that support *RFC 5987* will use `filename*` parameter and old user agents will ignore it and will use `filename` instead.

Comment: I get the same with a browser, although I didn't mention it (gonna edit); I tried your solution, it still doesn't work, plus now cUrl says there are `5 bytes remaining to read`.